# extract first attribute value with regexp

Tags: javascript

If I have string like

```
var a = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1251"?> .. encoding="utf-8"';
```

how to extract only value of first occurance of **encoding** attribute **only inside xml tag** with regexp?
So in result would be

```
Windows-1251
```

?

Comment: I strongly suggest to use parser. JavaScript possesses quite capable xml parsing features.

Comment: I use cheerio parser and it seems it cannot handle tags starting with ?. Any other parsers aren't accepted, regexp is the only way.

Comment: `/\sencoding\=\"(.*?)\"/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use a regex, as is your question, you may use

```
var val = a.match(/<\?xml[^>]+\s+encoding="([^"]*)"/)[1];
```

Note that usually, parsing the string, especially in a browser, is the simplest solution.

Because if you want to account for all cases, for example the possibility that you have `encoding=` at the end of an attribute value, then it starts to be nasty :

```
var val = a.match(/<\?xml(\s+[^>="]+="[^"]+")*\s+encoding="([^"]*)"/)[1];
```

Note that if you're not sure the attribute is present, you should check that the returned array isn't null before taking the element at index 1.

Comment: Usage of regex for xml is strongly not recommended [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: downvote for stringtforward solution. It will not work if I have some other attributes with values before encoding - therefore I would have to specify other element number of array.

Comment: The downvote is not just because xml and regex are inherently incompatible. Your suggestion may match invalid values, e.g. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root encoding="windows-1251"/>`

Comment: @dystroy I'd rather stay away from it anyways